# How can i redirect to some url if user directly enters the link. Also, if button already exists to a specific url (in spring boot)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a post method which simply update something to my database but there is loophole
I have settled this method to button with onclick using javascript and when button clicked it blocks button for other 10 seconds
but when I tried with direct URL it doesn't disables button for 30 seconds why ?

here is my post mapping code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Balnce_add", method ={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView GoesUp(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails currentuser) throws IOException {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
    int x=currentuser.getBalance() +10;
    currentuser.setBalance(x);
    repo.setUserInfoById(x,currentuser.getId());
    repoofdata.setDataInfoById(x,currentuser.getId());
    System.out.println(currentuser.getName()+" (new balance) ==> " +currentuser.getBalance());
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+"/game1");    // here game1 is HTML page with getmapping
     }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+"/signin");   // here signing is HTML page with getmapping
}
```

and here is my HTML code with on click javascript function

```
    <button  id="upside" onclick="up(true)" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Up</button>
```